# How to call another function from a function in class component React.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have a crud app to manage students, I want to refresh the student listing whenever I delete a student. But when I am calling the refresh function in the delete function it is throwing an error that my refresh function is not a function.
Below is the code of both functions:

```
deleteStudent(studentId) {
        axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/students/delete-student/' + studentId)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('Student successfully deleted!')
            this.loadStudents()
            
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }

loadStudents() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/students/')
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                students: res.data
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
```

Prior thanks for any help!

Comment: You haven't bind your function. Or you can use arrow function: loadStudents = () => {...}.

Comment: Declare `loadStudents` *before* `deleteStudent`. Also, ensure proper `this` bindings always.

Comment: The order of the functions doesn't matter, obviously.

Comment: Can you add some code showing where `deleteStudent` is called. How a function is called determines what the value of `this` is.

Comment: you need to filter students in state by student id after removing student

Comment: This is why you have to bind the function to (this) in the constructor to get this class as scope. But with arrow function this is this class anyway.

Comment: @IsaToltar, yes if you don't want to reload all students, but you need the server awnser to know if the deletion worked before delete it in the local store to be sync with your data base. This is more efficient if the server return just a status or an HTTP_CODE when you send a DELETE (crud)  methode (less data to transfert).

Comment: @JB_DELR Binding the deleteStudent to (this) in the constructor solved the issue. Thanks a ton.
Thank you, everybody.

Comment: Please consider arrow function for less code, and @IsaToltar comment because it's not necessary to overload your server.

Comment: @JB_DELR IsaToltar  
Sure I will take that into account, thanks for the suggestion.